# Batch Script Compare

Tags: batch-file

Have a basic batch script which updates a postgreSQL table with the users MAC against what is hard coded within the script. When I run it, it thinks both the MAC addresses are different or my syntax it not working. I have tried echo out the variables and they look the same.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

```
@echo off

set mac=00:00:00:00
echo %mac%
set /p mac_address= Please enter the MAC address 
echo %mac_address%
if mac==mac_address (

set /p hostname= Please enter the server ip address 

echo "update license set lldld" >> run
SET PGPASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx
postgresql\bin\psql -U postgres -h %hostname% -p 5434 -d jasperserver -a -f run
del run

) else (
Echo "Error with MAC code"
pause

    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `if mac==mac_address` compares the texts `mac` and `mac_address` not the content of the variables.

You (nearly) always need to expand variables with percents or exclamation marks.

```
if "%mac%"=="%mac_address%" echo Same
```

Comment: Doh! Been a long time, that's my excuse and I am sticking to it. Thanks so much!